# GTK+ application looks broken on Windows 10, but only sometimes

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I have built a GTK application for Windows and Linux that features checkbuttons and comboboxes.

Things work just fine for most users, but a minority of Windows users report bizarre glitches like the ones below: the dropdown menu doesn't open if you click on it, and the checkboxes are responsive but always not toggled (even though by default they are supposed to be toggled).

The thing is, I cannot even reproduce the bug because things work normally on my own Windows 10 boxes.

What could be the cause for different behaviors of GTK+ on different installations of Windows with the exact same version?

[image: Broken GTK]

Comment: And the code is.....

Comment: Irrelevant, I cannot reproduce this bug even myself. This is either a system issue or a GTK issue with the default widgets

Comment: If you can not provide a code or at least if you can not be more precise to your problem, than it is impossible to understand the whole picture here. Anyway, you definitely need to run your application with a Debugger (On Linux and Windows) and monitor the whole process behavior. It is more likely that you have some buggy code somewhere in that code.